# Database [] not configured - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-migrations

I have searched a lot about it and tried every possible solution I could find or think of.

So I am changing database configuration to a new database as follows:

```
DB::disconnect('mysql');
config(['database.connections.mysql.database' => $new_db_name]);
```

If i try to get the database name like:

```
dd(config('database.connections.mysql.database'));
```

I get the right database name which I just set. But when i try to run migration on it:

```
\Artisan::call('migrate', ['--database' => $new_db_name ]);
```

I get the error : **Database [$new_db_name] not configured**

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `--database` parameter is quite confusing. It shouldn't hold database name but database connection name, so in your case:

```
\Artisan::call('migrate', ['--database' => 'mysql' ]);
```

should do the trick.

Comment: There was a problem of absence of migrations table when switching to new database and calling `artisan migrate` but that's out of scope of this problem. Your answer is indeed right and acceptable. Thanks.